# Is there a way to write small text directly over particular letters in HTML?

Tags: html, string, subscript, superscript

Complete amateur here. I am working on a little personal project and need to be able to put numbers **directly over** over certain letters like this:

[image]

My current method is to just embed the equations as jpegs, but would like to know if there is a better way to do this (preferably, but not necessarily, in pure HTML)? (Hopefully something like the /above function on Microsoft word) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the superscript and subscript tags.

```css
sup {
  left: -.5em;
  top: -.5em;
  margin-left: -1em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
K<sub>2</sub>Cr<sub>2</sub><sup>+6</sup>O<sub>7</sub>
```

Are you looking for something like this? It may require some fine-tuning based on the exact formula you are trying to represent, but I think it works as a proof-of-concept.

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much, I don't know why using CSS never occurred to me, I have been thinking about this for days! I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! Similar to Alessio, I'd also recommend looking into typesetting libraries like MathJax or (my favorite) [Katex](https://katex.org/) that can help make things less cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can with HTML only, but there is [mathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) which is

> a JavaScript display engine for mathematics that works in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, that is certainly something I will look into.